# Can I display an error if the api cannot return the search?

Tags: javascript, api

So I am building an player tracker for players in the NBA, if someone misspells the players name or types a random thing that the api cannot fetch how can I alert that?

```
 function getResults (query) {
        fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=${searchbox.value}`)
        .then(player =>{
            return player.json()
        }) .then(displayResults);
    };

    function displayResults(player){
        playerName.innerHTML = player.data[0].first_name;
        playerLastName.innerHTML = player.data[0].last_name;
        teamName.innerHTML = player.data[0].team.full_name;
        playerPos.innerHTML = player.data[0].position;
    }
```

Comment: in `catch` throw an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request is actually throwing an error, you can use a `.catch()` to catch errors before they're thrown, like this:

```js
function getResults (query) {
  fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=${searchbox.value}`)
  .then(player => {
    return player.json()
  })
  .then(displayResults)
  .catch(displayError);
};

function displayError(error) {
  // Parse and display your error in the UI
}
```

However, if the request is properly formatted and the API is available then `fetch()` will still give you the response without throwing an error. In this case, you can check the status of the response in your `.then()`:

```js
function getResults (query) {
  fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=${searchbox.value}`)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    }

    // If `response.ok` is `false`, you can get the status code for more information on why, or the API may send an error message in the body:
    console.log(response.status) // Check http://httpstatuses.com/ for more info on the different statuses
    response.json()
  })
  .then(displayResults)
  .catch(displayError);
};
```